# Highcharts: connectNulls == false doesn't work in stack area chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Per highcharts area-stacked demo as link below:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked/

I change series data in jsfiddle with below json and set connectNull as false.
I want gap like cliff in null value period.
But neighbor of null value points connect each other at 0 level.
I set it as null, not 0. It should have a gap, not connected.

Is there any solution for this issue?

```
series: [{
            name: 'Asia',
            data: [502, 809, 809, null, 1402, 3634, 5268]
        }, {
            name: 'Africa',
            data: [106, 107, 111, null, 221, 767, 1766]
        }, {
            name: 'Europe',
            data: [163, 203, 276, null, 547, 729, 628]
        }, {
            name: 'America',
            data: [18, 31, 54, null, 339, 818, 1201]
        }, {
            name: 'Oceania',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, null, 30, 46]
        }]
```

Comment: You need to disable stacking option

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using stacking in your area graph.  If you turn that off, you get the cliff you want.  But, with stacking on, highcharts seems to treat nulls as zeros.